# I want to make a double column in SQL but it turn into a BIGINT instead

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, 
(total_deaths/total_cases)*100 AS death_percentage 
FROM public.covid_deaths
ORDER BY location, date;
```

Here the death percentage multiplies a decimal like 0.0027384 for example but when I try the query it appears as 0 and the column type is BIGINT instead of a double.
Does anyone know why this is?

(I'm using postgreSQL)

Comment: integer division......

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag because you said you are using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, 
(total_deaths*1.0/total_cases)*100 AS death_percentage 
FROM public.covid_deaths
ORDER BY location, date;
```

Could you please try this

Comment: or even `*100.0` instead of `*1.0` (and remove the `*100`)

Comment: You could use the expression `100.00*total_deaths/total_cases` and eliminate a multiplication.

Comment: That returns a `numeric` and a `double` was wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast at least one part of the expression to `double` to get double result. Using 1.0 results only in single precision float.

Try:

```
SELECT location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, 
total_deaths*100::double precision /total_cases AS death_percentage 
FROM public.covid_deaths
ORDER BY location, date;
```